# Subdomain issue with cakephp application

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp-2.0

I have a cakephp application running on shared hosting server. Now I want to add a staging server for testing purpose. I defined a subdomain, and made changes in htaccess files, but these things don't work. Please suggest what should I change more.
I know similar questions have already asked on stackoverflow but nothing works for me.

sudomain name staging.example.com
Here root folder .htaccess code is mentioned here:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example.com$
RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example.com$
RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

and .htaccess file from app/webroot from staging:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Is there any issue with such code or have to add more changes in another files.

Library is also installed in subdomain. Version of cake is 2.5.

Comment: *How* don't they work? More info please.

Comment: It is showing default godaddy blank page. I think it is generated because of error 500.

Answer (score 0):

This condition:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example.com$
```

will not match your subdomain hence `RewriteRule` won't fire.

Just change your rule to this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .* app/webroot/$0 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks Anubhava, but it does not make any change.

Comment: Do you have any other rule in this .htaccess? Also post your `webroot/.htaccess` in question.

Comment: Code from webroot is added now.

Comment: What os `DocumentRoot` of `staging.example.com`? Make sure it is same as the root of main domain.

Comment: yes documentroot is same for both. var/www/public_html.

Comment: In that case, there is nothing in rewrite rules that is behaving differently for `subdomain`. Do you have something in `cackephp` config differently for `subdomain`.